# Was this person killed by someone else at the end of "I Want to Eat Your Pancreas"?

Tags: i-want-to-eat-your-pancreas

I just finished *Kimi no Suizou wo Tabetai* the movie as well as the manga. I found out that the main heroine (Sakura Yamaguchi) was found dead with a knife on her chest.

I’m wondering if she got killed by someone and if so, who was that and why did he/she do so?

My guess: I strongly believe that her ex-boyfriend murdered her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the main heroine was killed by a random slasher unknown to the main character**.

The murderer's name was never mentioned in all media (light novel, live-action film, manga, anime movie), but it's the random slasher that has been mentioned a few times in the story (in the newspaper, on the TV news). It's unknown to the main character as he said,

> 山内桜良は、以前から世間を騒がせていた通り魔事件に巻き込まれた。どこの誰だかも知らない犯人は、すぐに捕まった。
>
> Sakura Yamauchi got dragged into the random slasher ([通り魔](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A%E9%AD%94)) case that has been disturbing the society since then. The culprit whom I don't know was quickly arrested.

Since this is a random slasher case, there's no particular reason why they were attacking someone: **she was just happened to be in the wrong place at the wrong time**.

---

<sup>That said, the point of that scene is not about who the murderer was or why she was murdered, but why it happened despite the main topic about "pancreas".</sup>